# can more than one snapshot DELETE be run at a time?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_stopping_currently_running_snapshot_and_restore_operations) states that:

> The snapshot and restore framework allows running only one snapshot or one restore operation at a time

However, it is unclear as to whether one can have more than one snapshot DELETE operation at the same time.  The API seems to not accept wildcards or a comma separated list of snapshots, unlike other APIs, but it is not clear whether I have to deal limit concurrency as well.

For example, although the specified wildcard does match a valid snapshot, this returns an error:

```
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/_snapshot/backups/snapshot_149990988893*"

{
   "error" : { 
      "type" : "snapshot_missing_exception",
      "root_cause" : [
         {
            "reason" : "[backups:snapshot_149990988893*] is missing",
            "type" : "snapshot_missing_exception"
         }
      ],
      "reason" : "[backups:snapshot_149990988893*] is missing"
   },
   "status" : 404
}
```

I need to know whether I need to restrict my automated backup system to one snapshot DELETE at a time by restricting concurrency in some fashion.  I don't think I can easily create a test to verify concurrency behavior.

Comment: The DELETE snapshot endpoint only accepts exact snapshot names. Probably to prevent deleting too many snapshots by mistake. Nothing prevents you from running multiple deletion at the same time. ES will tell if it doesn't like it, otherwise, everything will be fine.

Comment: "ES will tell f you if it doesn't like it".   It's hard to induce a problem because it's a concurrency issue.  Those are usually very hard to test.

Comment: to be clear, this is devops code.  I have to know what the errors are in advance.  No humans in the loop.

Comment: You need to try it out chaos-monkey style ;-)

Comment: LOL.  Black box software FTW

Answer (score 0):

At least on v.6, ES won't let you run delete a snapshot while another one is being deleted. In these cases, you'll see an error like this (this one if from python + `elasticsearch-py` library)

```
TransportError: TransportError(503, u'concurrent_snapshot_execution_exception', u'[<repository>:<snapshot>] cannot delete - another snapshot is currently being deleted')
```